# AngularJS issue injecting services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Not really sure where I'm going wrong here. I'm trying to simply inject a service and use it in controller

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.controllers.myCtrl',
    'myApp.services.myService'
]);
```

js/controllers/myCtrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers.myCtrl', []);

app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, MyService) {
     ...
});
```

js/services/myService.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.services.myService', []);

app.service("MyService", function ($http, $q) {
     ...
});
```

This results in the following error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are trying to access `myService` service component of `myApp.services.myService` module in `myApp.controllers.myCtrl` module, without injecting the module will obviously going to get failed.

If you wanted to access the service in `myApp.controllers.myCtrl` module then you need to inject `myApp.services.myService` in the `[]`(dependency array where you can all dependent module).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers.myCtrl', ['myApp.services.myService']);
```

By doing above line you do have all component(services) in `myApp.controllers.myCtrl` module.

Answer (score 0):

js/controllers/myCtrl.js

var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers.myCtrl', ['myApp.services.myService']);

app.controller('homeController', function ($scope, MyService) {
     ...
});

**Then not need to inject services in app.js again.**

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers.myCtrl']);